# Ajax polling seems stuck ONLY at the last request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, polling

I'm using Ajax polling to poll the server for the percentage progress. In case you're wondering, I'm not using setInterval since that can lead to multiple requests starving each other. I'm using setTimeout in the "complete" callback of jQuery.ajax(), and am setting a time out of 5000 ms for the next request.

So ajax calls are made at approximately 5-7 second intervals (depending on how long the previous ajax call took to respond, and it progresses slowly from 0% to 100%.

The problem is that while all ajax calls made seem to work fine and almost on time, only the last ajax call gets delayed. And it doesn't get delayed in getting the response from the server. The last ajax call itself is made after a very long delay of about 2 minutes.

**I've searched and read all similar questions/answers on SO, and my scenario seems unique in that only the last check status request get's delayed, while  all other requests work fine.**

The server logs for this ajax call give me the following pattern in almost all the tests (this is an example) :

- **Ajax request 1: made at 0 seconds - Returned 0% progress**
- **Ajax request 2: made at 7 seconds - Returned 17% progress**
- **Ajax request 3: made at 13 seconds - Returned 30% progress**
- **Ajax request 4: made at 20 seconds - Returned 54% progress**
- **Ajax request 5: *made at 157 seconds* - Returned 100% progress**

My code is as follows, if you need it:

```
var makeNextAjaxCall = true;
function ajaxCaller(url, data) {
    $.post({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.progress === 100) {
                makeNextAjaxCall = false;
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            if(makeNextAjaxCall) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    ajaxCaller(url, data);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've spent days trying to find the cause of why the last ajax call is only the one that's delayed, and not even by the server, but the client itself.

Comment: Have you tried changing the timeout to 20000ms or 1000ms to see what happens?

Comment: My guess is that the third request takes a lot of time for the server to respond back which delay the last call that returns 100%

Comment: @J.Nicastro No Good suggestion will try once

Comment: @AlonEitan As I stated on my question, the last request itself is made by ajax after 2 minutes gap instead of 5 seconds so it does not seem to be a delay caused by the server. Further, this happens even in cases where 4-5 requests were made in total and even in cases where 10-20 requests were made in total.

Comment: @AlonEitan Also why would the server only delay the second last request, always? There is no particular extra thing happening in the second last request that could delay it always. Please help me more if you can. Thanks

Comment: @NavkarJain did you noticed anything after the change?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know :( how do you return the progress percentage on the server? Do you save it in a session variable / fetch it from the DB? I would suggest that you also log the execution time on the server (save the current time before the main code execution and the current time just before you respond back to the client) - It will give you indication if the unexplained delay happens on the server or the client side

Comment: @J.Nicastro I haven't tried that till now as I'm first trying to get better logs of the timestamps. Will let you know how it goes when I do change it..

Comment: @AlonEitan That's exactly what I'm trying to do now.. will post the results